# Change the caption of the tables

Tags: tables, captions, align, elsarticle

I want to change the caption of the tables to be exactly like this:
[image: elsarticle]

My code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,caption,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\myrange{$[-100, 100]$}
\settowidth\mylen{\myrange}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain,
    labelfont=bf,
    labelsep=newline,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    skip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table caption here.}
    \label{my-label}
    $\begin{array}{@{}ll lcC{\mylen} @{}}
    \toprule
    \text{Function} & f_{\min} & \text{Search} \text{range} \\ 
    \midrule       
    \begin{aligned} 
    &f_{1}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{2}  
    \end{aligned}  
    & 0 & [-100, 100]\\
    \bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table} 


\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{The specific parameters of the algorithms used in the comparison}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ZZZZ} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Parameter} \\     \toprule
    AAA                           & $L = P \times D$\\
    BBB                            & $X_0 = 1$\\
    CCC                           & 0                            \\
    DDD                           & 0    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{ccccccc}
    \caption{My caption for this table}
    \label{foo}\\
    \hline
    AA &   & BBB & CCC & DDD & SSA & EEE\\
    \hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \multirow{4}{*}{F1} 
    & X 
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000 \\
    & Y 
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000 \\
    & Z 
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000 \\
    & W 
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000   
    & 00000000000 \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: If you are using `elsarticle` you are presumably submitting to a journal or conference which uses it. Hence, this style is not up to you and you should not change it. If you aren't submitting, you are better advised to use a standard class which is easier to customise.

Comment: @cfr I have download elsarticle template from this page [link](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions), but, the caption of the table is not as required.

Answer (score 3):

- at `elsarticle` you use `review` option. it increase line spacing.  consequently document has more vertical spaces in each line, even in captions. if you remove this option, i.e.: use `\documentclass{elsarticle}` instead of `\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}` than the line spacing become equal to `\baselineskip`.
- long table is wider than text width,
- caption of long table you can move to the left with `\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}`

```
\begingroup
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccc}
    \caption{My caption for this table}
    \label{foo}\\
    \hline
    AA &   & BBB & CCC & DDD & SSA & EEE\\
...
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

with this changes you will obtain:

[image]

however, you should consider [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) comment below your question.

Comment: where can I find the**draft option**? If I use the **elsarticle template**, I will not get the caption of the table as required. What I should do in this case?

Comment: @shdotcom,  sorry,  it should be `review`. now corrected in answer. my mwe start with `\documentclass{elsarticle}`.